# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android, bluetooth

There is the XML layout

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lab02pc19.imhere.FragmentBluetooth">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_connected"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="miImagen" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am working on an app that works with Bluetooth and I need that the app turns on and turn off the cell phone Bluetooth on the click of ImageView.

This is the mistake

```
05-25 07:43:41.129 18314-18314/com.example.lab02pc19.imhere E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.lab02pc19.imhere, PID: 18314
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickImagen(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imablue'
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

There is my java code

```
package com.example.lab02pc19.imhere;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentOpciones.OnFragmentInteractionListener,FragmentBluetooth.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
   ImageView miimagen;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        miimagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imablue);
        View view = new View(this);


        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bluetoothAdapter==null){
            miimagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            setEstadoBluetooth(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void view(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    }

    private void setEstadoBluetooth(boolean enabled) {
    }

    private void setImageBluetooth(boolean enabled) {
    }
    public void clickima(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.imablue:
                setEstadoBluetooth();
                break;

        }
    }

    public void setImagenBluetooth(Boolean valor){
        if(valor) miimagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetooth_connected);
        else miimagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetooth);
    }
    public void setEstadoBluetooth(){
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            setImagenBluetooth(false);
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();

        }
        else{
            setImagenBluetooth(true);
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
                Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_opciones){
         fragment = new FragmentOpciones();
            FragmentTransaction = true;

        }else if(id== R.id.nav_Bluetooth){
            fragment = new FragmentBluetooth();
            FragmentTransaction = true;



        }
        if(FragmentTransaction){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
            item.setChecked(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your xml layout as well.

Comment: As per your code it feels like you have mentioned onClick method in xml and didn't declare corresponding function in java code.

Comment: There is the XML, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file inside **ImageView** you have written `android:onClick="miImagen"` it means on clicking that imageview a method named as
**miImagen** will be called .

But you haven't written any **miImagen()** method in your java code. So you have to create a method named as **miImagen** and perform desired fuctionality inside that method.

Moreover in your java code you have written:

```
miimagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imablue);
```

But in your xml there is no such imageView having id as **imablue**. I think in above line of code instead **imablue** it should be **imageView2** which is the ID of your imageView in your xml file.

Comment: I think that this is the method that i have to create: public void miImagen(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView2:
            setEstadoBluetooth();
            break;

    }
} 
But where exactly?

Comment: You can place it anywhere inside the MainActivity. And there no need of placing switch case inside the method as it will be called automatically when user taps on imageView2 because you have defined it in xml .In short you can straight away write this: `public void miImagen() { setEstadoBluetooth();}`